# How to create Wordpress login for different users, with different roles?

Tags: plugins, redirect, login, user-roles

I need to create a web page. where the user / group of users, after logging in through the portal (using the provided login credentials), will be redirected to the relevant page with their **own** information,links and data.

At first, I thought to create for each group of users, a separate page with their information. But what if one day there are many groups?
Is there a plugin that, when the user logs in, sees the same info page / platform, but with their individual/personal data (the idea is like hotmail, or yahoo)?

Thank you in advance!